# jQuery - Grouped Image Gallery [first image no show]

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, colorbox

http://www.jasontanzer.com/behind-the-lens.asp

Click the first Image, Does not load until you click the arrows inside the jQuery colorbox.

Not sure what is causing the first image to never load. Just a spinning .gif for me. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: are you using image load to display first image. looks like a timing issue or the Image is not ready on the load of popup.

Comment: thanks for responding, not sure what is going on. check it again @ http://www.jasontanzer.com/behind-the-lens.asp No Matter what image you click first, that image has an issue loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the slideshow speed to about 3500 in colorbox.js.

Thus

> Blockquote

slideshowSpeed: 3500,

> Blockquote

instead of 2500. I also think it's a timing issue. Also make sure the file sizes of your photos are not too large thus slowing down load times. Lower res photos might work better.

Comment: looking at the load times makes me fairly sure your photo resolutions and therefore sizes are too high. It's natural as a photographer to want the best quality photos but slideshows can drag.

Comment: They seem fine with loading, except the first one. I have saved the thumbnails and larger images at 80/100 Jpeg. Are we sure its the photos? I would hate to have to re-batch them all.

Comment: save one of the photos at a lower res size and see how that effects the load time.

Comment: Did the fix work for you?You can check it off. The page looks good.